# How to smooth the curve and eliminate the overshoot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have designed a GUI where I have to plot the data of different sensors. Whenever I plot data `self.ax.plot(plotting, "ro-")`, everything is fine. But when I try to smooth the curve using interpolation method, there is some overshooting in the smooth curve. Both the curves are plotted to have a better understanding. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code snippet

```
def draw1(self):
    if self.b1.isChecked() == True:

        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        for i in range(0,1):
            self.ax.clear()
        slot = float(self.DataArraySorted[0])
        plotting.append(slot)
        x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
        y_knots = plotting
        x_knots = list(range(len(y_knots)))
        poly_deg = 3
        coefs = np.polyfit(x_knots, y_knots, poly_deg)
        y_poly = np.polyval(coefs, x)
        self.ax.plot(x, y_poly, "-")
        self.ax.plot(plotting, "ro-")
        self.ax.legend(['Sensor 1'], loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.71, 1.08))
        self.ax.set_ylim([0,1023])
        self.canvas.update()
        self.canvas.flush_events()
        self.canvas.draw()
```

You can see the picture here

[image]

Comment: Isn't it pretty ambiguous what the interpolated function should do outside the range  of the data?

Comment: Or in other words, there is no overshoot inside the fitted data range and since the fit only makes sense inside the data range, one should not display it outside of it. Could it be that you don't actually want to perform a fit? But use some other smoothing technique?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest some other smoothing technique? Can you suggest some ??

Comment: Splines, rolling mean, gaussian filtering or other frequency filters... it all depends on what you are trying to achieve here. If you can name the purpose of the line, one may know which technique suits best.